# Trying to use the Google App Engine to search the Twitter API, but coming across issues that may be GAE specific

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, twitter, twitter-oauth

So I've got my application registered with Twitter and all, got my four keys to use. I found the searching script on an online tutorial and this is what I got.

```
import json
import oauth2 as oauth

access_token = "3309947392-8Ynx4uOXC63dFM9yeABJDmfkhak5b9DyN9WeloJ"
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = "GEsMKJfyKfUMnh7lkiLRdPZfK"
consumer_secret = ""

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
access_token = (access_token, access_token_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)

timeline_endpoint = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=whatsrelevancy&count=1"

response, data = client.request(timeline_endpoint)


tweets = json.loads(data)
for tweet in tweets:
    print data
```

I tested it on the site with my app.yaml assuming this as the primary page and assuming that it would simply post the raw received data. The error message I received was "ImportError: no module named oauth2." Remembering that Google App Engine recommends that when downloading third party libraries, it suggests downloading them directly into a 'lib' directory. I change line 2 to

```
from lib import oauth2 as oauth
```

Now my error message with "ImportError: no module named lib." I had followed all of the directions for the appengine_config.py but even with that, it still didn't work. After a bit of digging I found that there had to be some sort of import path redirect added to the main.py:

```
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
import fix_path

import views

url_map = [('/', views.IndexHandler)]

app = webapp.WSGIApplication(url_map, debug=False)

def main():
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and some more in a separate fix_path.py file:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))
```

I ran this and the error message I received was "ImportError: no module named views". I looked into the views file and, regrettably, I am a bit confused. What exactly, in regards to me, is the views.py fie meant to consist of? Is there a better way to redirect the path? Is there a better way to get the API information I need? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to run this on GAE? That's for hosting a web app itself, ie if you presented a web page to search Twitter and show the results somehow. The code you have is not a web app and can just be run from your computer.

Comment: My end goal is to create the web app that uses this code to search twitter. I wrote some code whose purpose is to search tweets that I pull from the API looking for specific keywords that I have listed in a dictionary with a corresponding ranking system that I have attributed to it. As it is, I can run this code from my computer for basic text but I wanted to test it against actual tweets successfully pulled using the Twitter API. My end goal is to have an actual web app to show these results (ie the total point value of a group of tweets from a given user’s account).

Comment: Fine but in that case you should *start* with a web app, and then integrate the Twitter search. Do the GAE tutorial for example and learn how to create a basic app with a view handler and template and how to deploy and run it; then you can start working out how your search would work in that environment.

Comment: I’ve already done the “hello world” tutorial and I didn’t find that quite useful in regards to the handlers or in creating my own app. Am I missing something? Just a little background, I am a 15-year-old high school sophomore who is trying to create a web app for a project and am still learning as I go. I apologize if I’m not very knowledgeable. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You haven't imported `views.py`.  It is looking in that file for a class called `IndexHandler()`

Comment: Importing views.py seems to be where I am getting stuck. I don’t know what is supposed to be in views.py and I’m afraid I don’t know how to create the IndexHandler(). I’m currently following a step by step on Google Cloud Platform for developing python apps on GAE. I feel like this shouldn’t be as hard as I’m making it.